# Вывод данных в Excel на отдельный лист

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic

Необходимо результат вычисления данных на одном листе представить в виде столбца в другом. Конкретно: вычисляется разность двух столбцов (один элемент одного столбца с соответствующим элементом другого столбца). Столбец вывести на отдельный (заранее готовый) лист той же книги. Ниже приведён макрос, который выводит значения на тот же лист:

```
Dim a, i&, r&
    a = Range("B2:D660").Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        r = a(i, 2) - a(i, 1)
        a(i, 3) = IIf(r < 0, 0, r)
    Next
    Range("B2:D660") = a
    For Each cc In [D2:D660]
    If cc.Value = "0" Then cc.Offset(0, 0) = "ALL OKAY"
    Next
```

Требуется переделать его (при желании - написать новый) так, чтобы значения выводились на другой лист.

Comment: `cc.Offset(0, 0)  = сс` - нет никакого смысла в таком смещении. Еще один узелок на память: "0" - это тест, не число ноль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй цикл не нужен - сразу проверяем полученное значение.

```
Sub Result_()
Dim a()
Dim i&
    a = Range("B2:C660").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        a(i, 1) = a(i, 2) - a(i, 1)
        If a(i, 1) <= 0 Then a(i, 1) = "ALL OKAY"
    Next i

    Worksheets("result").Range("B2").Resize(UBound(a), 1).Value = a
End Sub
```

Игнорируем значения <=0

```
Sub Result2_()
Dim a()
Dim dRes As Double
Dim i As Long, k As Long
    a = Range("B2:C660").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        dRes = a(i, 2) - a(i, 1)

        If dRes > 0 Then
            k = k + 1: a(k, 1) = dRes
        End If
    Next i

    Worksheets("result").Range("B2").Resize(k, 1).Value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы отрицательные и нулевые значения не выводились?

Comment: Вы проверили макрос? Строка перед `Next i` следит за этим и заменяет число на текст

Comment: Да, проверил, но хотелось бы, чтобы отрицательные и нулевые значения полностью игнорировались, не принимали форму сообщения "ALL OKAY"

Comment: Дополнил ответ - выводим только положительные числа. `dRes As Double` - такое расширение на случай, если встречаются дробные значения .

Comment: Неправильно вычисляются значения. Дробные значения встречаться не будут, в них нет необходимости

Comment: Неправильно - как? Что нек так? Дробных не будет - ничего страшного. Хотите, замените `Double`  на `Long`

Comment: Разность между столбцами неправильно вычисляется. Например - в первой же ячейке должно было получиться 2, у вас вычисляется как 3. И так - почти во всех ячейках

Comment: Не должно быть сдвига по строкам?

Comment: Если это и есть причина неправильности вычислений - то да, пожалуй, не должно быть:)

Comment: Да откуда знать, что Вы там вычисляете! Макрос берет разность двух значений. Если не сдвигать по строкам: в первом макросе замените две строки внутри цикла на эту: 'If a(i, 2) - a(i, 1) > 0 Then a(i, 1) = a(i, 2) - a(i, 1)'. Или проще - `"ALL OKAY"` заменить на `Empty`. Не просто копируйте полученное решение. Учитесь читать код. 'F1' в помощь.

Comment: Или во втором коде убрать переменую `k`  и записать `If dRes > 0 Then a(i, 1) = dRes`

Comment: Вам не обязательно знать, что я вычисляю:). Там целые значения и этого должно быть достаточно для решения задачи. Empty не решение - он оставляет пустые ячейки, а их быть не должно. Примечательно, что в первом макросе всё вычисляется правильно, но есть лишние ячейки (отрицательные и нулевые значения), а во втором неправильно вычисляется разность. Я пробовал решать по другому, менять переменные в условиях - не помогло. Спасибо вам за помощь и потраченное время, сам попробую ещё повозиться - авось получится

Comment: Так задачу нужно описывать правильно... То Вам текст нужен, то не нужен, то только положительные выводить, то строки игнорировать... Проверьте второй макрос, подправил переменную. При желании замените `Double` на `Long`, будет меньше памяти кушать

Comment: Буду знать. Огромное спасибо за помощь - теперь всё правильно